# Labels in Java for exception handling

Tags: java, loops

I'm doing the Java Associate level certification and while we are expressly told we won't be tested on labels, we have been shown them. Looking on here though the advice seems to be never use labels?

I'd like to use them in a catch block/user input console as a means of validating input.

```
do {//Keep calculator going as long as user wants               
            numInputCheck: 
            do {
                try {//Force user to input a whole number
                    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the Mark you want to Calculate\n(Enter marks between " + GradeCalculator.getMIN_MARK() + " and " + GradeCalculator.getMAX_MARK() + " only): ");
                    mark = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());
                }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid entry - Please ensure entry is a number only.");
                    continue numInputCheck;
                }   
                gradeCalc.isValidMark(mark);//Ensure input is within valid range
            }while(!gradeCalc.getIsValidMark());
            *etc*......
```

Is this bad coding?

EDIT: The code above wasn't doing what I thought it was/wanted it to do - it wasn't actually jumping back to the label at all.

I ended up changing the code to

```
do {//Keep calculator going as long as user wants
            do {//Force user to enter number within valid range
                do {//Force user to enter a whole number
                    try {
                        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the Mark you want to Calculate\n(Enter marks between " + GradeCalculator.getMIN_MARK() + " and " + GradeCalculator.getMAX_MARK() + " only): ");
                        mark = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());
                        isValidInput = true;
                    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.println("\nInvalid entry - Please ensure entry is a number only.");
                        isValidInput = false;
                    }
                }while(!isValidInput);
            }while(!gradeCalc.isValidMark(mark));
```

which I'm *fairly* sure is working correctly.

Anyway, I think I answered my own question - labels are discouraged because people like me try to use them.

Comment: I don't think the label serves much purpose in this exact example, because `continue` should apply to the inner `do` loop by default.  I might not go so far as to say this is _bad_ coding, but I think most Java gurus would say labels should not be used unless they are needed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This comment is a pretty good answer :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @tim no, continue will jump to the `while` evaluation (possibly causing an NPE)

Comment: @Strelok So are you saying that `continue` would behave differently from `continue numInputCheck` ?  I was only commenting on the use of labels, not the rest of the code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim and others. Stupid question so, time to read the chapter on nesting loops...

Comment: The point by @Strelok seems valid.  You might want to make sure that the loop evaluation doesn't go NPE on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not actual example because continue can do all the job by itself without the help of the label .
 A good example is when you have 2 nested loops and you want to break the outer loop from a condition in the inner loop

```
    outerloop:while(condition1) {

                 while(condition2) {
                       if(condition3)
                           break outerloop;
                 }
          {
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue statement skips all sentences above, you have to use break sentence for stopping the loop. Labels are useful for more than one loop, for example:

```
label1:
for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j<10; j++){
        if (i+j = 3)
            break label1;
    }
}
```